# PDO SELECT Doesn't Complete or Throw Exception

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a page that queries a MySQL database to create a weblink by inserting a transaction id into the link. It's pretty straight forward as all I require is a specific ID from the user and click submit. From there, it should query and get the resulting transaction ID that I need.

I'm running this on an Ubuntu server with PHP 7.2 and Apache 2. I'm connecting to a MySQL server on another machine that's also running Ubuntu server. I have a PDO PHP class that I've used before that helps me set up the connection and prepare statements, create queries, etc. I can get it to the point of creating the connection to the MySQL server, but I don't get any results back and I don't see any exceptions thrown.

```
<?php
    include('databaseConnections.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--44656469636174656420746f20526179204d61686c6b65-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Link Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <form name="query" id="mainForm" method="post" action="">
            <input required type="text" name="claimNum" id="claimNum" size="12" maxlength="25" placeholder="Claim Number" value=''/> &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Get Link"/> &nbsp;
        </form>
        <?php
            function query() {
                try {
                    $getTransactID = new DatabaseConnection(); //Create new connection.
                    $getTransactID->query('SELECT transactionId FROM Claims WHERE claimNumber = :claimNum');
                    $getTransactID->bind(':claimNum', $_POST["claimNum"]);
                    $row = $getTransactID->fetch(); //Run query and return results.
                    $getTransactID = null; //Close the connection.

                    //Right now, I'm trying to get the result to show up.
                    echo '\n\n\n<pre>';
                    print_r($row);
                    echo '</pre>';

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo '
                    <div id="failure" class="subcontent">
                        <h1>Link Creation Error</h1>
                        <div>
                            '.$e.'
                            <br>
                            <p>Unable to get record from database. Contact an administrator for assistance.</p>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                }
            }

            if (isset($_POST["claimNum"])){
                query();
            }
        ?>
</body>
```

---

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private $mysqlConnString = 'mysql:host=xx.xx.x.xxx;dbname=data;charset=utf8';
    private $mysqlUser = 'userAcct';
    private $mysqlPassword = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    private $connection;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO($this->mysqlConnString, $this->mysqlUser, $this->mysqlPassword);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            error_log($e);
        }
    }

    public function setQuery($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    }

    public function executeQuery()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function returnResults()
    {
        $this->executeQuery();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        $this->executeQuery();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                    break;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function rowCount()
    {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function closeCursor()
    {
        $this->stmt->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

I expected to get the transaction ID to show up underneath my text box and submit button or for an exception and error to show up. Instead, It comes back as just the text box and submit button. I tried putting echo statements in between the database connection lines starting with $getTransactID = new DatabaseConnection();, but only the one directly under $getTransactID = new DatabaseConnection(); showed up. All the rest didn't.

EDIT: Issue resolved thanks to Barmar's comment. Turns out that I used a different method name in the page than the one defined I defined in the PDO class I'm using.

Comment: I see a `setQuery` function in your class, but you're using `->query()` in your first section of code.

Comment: Do you see `<pre>` if you do `View Source`?

Comment: Exceptions aren't thrown because you have a `try..catch (Exception $e)` in `function query()`. If you catch a more specific excepton,`PDOException`, you will likely get your errors.

Comment: @Barmar, no, I don't see a <pre> in View Source.

Comment: @adam, I swapped to PDOException in the index.php file, and it still doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @AndrewWallace Do you get a white screen(wsod)? or something else? If it is something else what is on screen? If you get a wsod, check your error logs.

Comment: @adam It just refreshes to the index.php screen with the text field and the submit button. The only difference is that if I look at the Console parameters after submitting, it will show the text that I entered is stored.

Comment: So `isset($_POST["claimNum"])` evaluates to true when you submit your form with a  claim number? If you want to display different content due to an exception being thrown you'll likely want to create a custom derived exception e.g. `class ResourceNotFoundException extends \Exception {}`. If records are NOT found from executing `fetch` throw an exception. Creating the custom derived exception is a suggestion, throwing `Exception` will work for this case too.

Comment: Change `Exception` to `Error` in your `catch`. That will catch the error from trying to call a nonexistent method `query()`.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for noticing that. It should be setQuery() instead. I changed the name to avoid confusion, which eventually caused confusion.

Comment: So is that the problem in the real code, or a copying error? If it's a copying error, why haven't you fixed it here? It would easily explain why the echo statements after that line didn't execute.

Comment: @Barmar, it was an issue in the actual code. That's fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar answered this question with one of his comments. It turns out that I had named a method setQuery() in the PDO class (which I made over two years ago), and in the page code I tried to call the method by the name query().